# .Net, asp Global.asa equivalent

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

In classic asp you had the Global.asa file, what's the equivalent in .Net?  I want a central point in which to create (once) a master DataSet that I want to be able to access throughout my application?  What would be the correct event, onStart?

Thanks R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application_Start in the Global.asax

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

I thought the Application_Init was the first to fire, but doesn't seem to be?!  Something else to check out.

Comment: My pleasure, Application_Init doesn't seem to be valid. You can try:
public override void Init()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
But the Start is the right place.

Answer (score 6):

The ASP.NET Equivalent is global.asax.

The [Official ASP.NET Web Site](http://asp.net) is an excellent resource. In particular, see [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/get-started/).

Comment: Thanks, I need to work my way through some of those tutorials, time is always a factor. :)

Comment: I strongly suggest you do this, or at least read a "Beginning ASP.NET Development" book. The differences are very great, especially the jump from VBSCRIPT to an OO language like VB.NET. You will otherwise spend too much time tripping over your thorough knowledge of an ancient technology (Classic ASP).

Answer (score 1):

Global.asax